# how to handle cascade delete exception in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, exception

On `cascade delete`, I want show message to user in `c#` when user wants to `delete` field and `occur exception`, but don't know `number of this error`. please help me.

```
try{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    if(ex.number == (?))
        MessageBox.Show("could not deleted, used in other tables");
}
```

Comment: Full list [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645603%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). But the best way to do the actual check is to produce such error manually and than check what the number is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Masoud,

This link has an interesting explanation on how to do that.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2007/08/01/mapping-sql-server-errors-to-net-exceptions-the-fun-way.aspx

You will have some something similar to that:

```
try
{
    db.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    if (ex.Errors.Count == 1) // Assume the interesting stuff is in the first error
    {
        switch (ex.Errors[0].Number)
        {
            case 547: // Foreign Key violation
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Some helpful description", ex);
                break;
            case 2601: // Primary key violation
                throw new DuplicateRecordException("Some other helpful description", ex);
                break;
            default:
                throw new DataAccessException(ex);
        }
    }
    else throw;
}
```

I'd recommend you to present an alternative to the user, just show the error message is not the best User Experience that you can provide. Maybe create a column to define the entry as inactive.

Comment: tank you for your answer